# Buy Product when Online with Python Selenium (and xpath?)

Tags: python

Assuming I want to buy a product (as fast as possible) on a website (for example: https://theebayshop.to/product/35)
how would I set it up with python selenium?
I already tried this but it didn't work:

```
driver.get("https://theebayshop.to/product/35")

Stock = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='app']/main[@class='py-4']/div[@class='container']/div[contains(@class,'row')]//div[contains(@class,'card')]/div[@class='card-header']/div[@class='stock-header']/div[@class='row']/div")

print(Stock)
```

Then I wanted to implement something like this: if Stock >=1 && <7 then...
But for that the xapth needs to work. I dont know why it doesnt show me the current "stock" output!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse your `xpath` like this to get the stock information.

```
//div[@id='app']/main[@class='py-4']/div[@class='container']/div[contains(@class,'row')]//div[contains(@class,'card')]/div[@class='card-header']/div[@class='stock-header']/div[@class='row']/div/font/font/text()
```

You can use `chrome` to test your `xpath` like this.

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! But it says that it's unable to find the element

Comment: @DenisSchulz I could able to get the element using this `xpath`.  Can you edit your question with your full code.

Comment: That's actually nearly my full code :/
Edit: Didn't know that "enter" means posting directly a comment but my code start with driver.get and then the website and then this:
Stock = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='app']/main[@class='py-4']/div[@class='container']/div[contains(@class,'row')]//div[contains(@class,'card')]/div[@class='card-header']/div[@class='stock-header']/div[@class='row']/div/font/font/text()")
And then print(Stock)

Comment: @DenisSchulz That's weird. Can you paste your output here. Aldo tries to change your driver as well.

Comment: Yes, it is: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='app']/main[@class='py-4']/div[@class='container']/div[contains(@class,'row')]//div[contains(@class,'card')]/div[@class='card-header']/div[@class='stock-header']/div[@class='row']/div/font/font/text()"}
  (Session info: chrome=106.0.5249.119)

Also, the driver works fine (just tested another program with it)

Comment: I also tried it like this but also without success: 
Stock = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div")

sleep(5)

print (Stock)

Instead it prints this: n="71b9bf9ad...", , element="0347...")

Comment: @DenisSchulz I think the response with the `403` status code (tested in scrapy). That means it doesn't have a proper response. Can you please cross-check that? I think it's due to the authentication issues from the website.